# Can i increase line spacing between the data that i am loading in web view?

Tags: android

Can i increase line spacing between the data that i am loading in web view?

```
web1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);               
            web1.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());              
            web1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            //web1.setInitialScale(65);
            web1.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(18);


            web1.loadData(htmldata,"text/html; charset=utf-8",null);
```

Comment: Why you do this? post your htmldata

Comment: If you are using the WebView to load a HTML, use the CSS `line-height` property.

Comment: i am using it but this is not working can you please tell correct statement if i am doing any mistake??

String htmldata = "" + "img{width:100%!important;height:auto!important;}iframe{width:100%!important;height:100%!important;}p{line-height:50px!important}" + "" + " "+c+"" + "";